# MariaDB + phpmyadmin with Ngnix on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am trying to install phpmyadmin + mariadb.

My PHP configure string has the following mysql flags

```
CONFIGURE_STRING="--prefix=/etc/php7 --enable-mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd  
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd <and other flags>"
```

I installed mariadb with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-client mariadb-server  
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

I can login with a password via

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Then I installed phpmyadmin with

```
cd /var/www/html
git clone --depth=1 --branch=STABLE https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.git
mv phpmyadmin datastore    #change name to datastore
```

When I open http://localhost/datastore I received the phpmyadmin login page; in attempt to login with root username and root password,  i received the following error:

```
#2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

                                           AND


mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory.
```

I am using php7 on ubuntu 14.04.

I wish to be able to connect mariadb and phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some directions from Git on how to solve the problem and these are my steps, I feel someone may encounter the same challenge.

In phpmyadmin copy config.sample.inc.php into config.inc.php

```
sudo cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php
```

Check MariaDB status with STATUS;

```
MariaDB [(none)]>STATUS; [ENTER]
```

Check Connection - if localhost via Unix Socket then copy unix socket value.

Go to config.inc.php and force the following

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock';
```

Then change permission of config.inc.php in phpmyadmin

```
sudo chmod 0755 config.inc.php
```

Point your browser to phpmyadmin and login with your username and password.

[Git link](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12291#issuecomment-222961234)